# Continuous Bag of Words NY Time Corpus

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings, word2vec, bag-of-words

I am working to implement the continuous bag of words approach on the New York Times corpus dataset. However, I am getting word embeddings that do not seem very useful based on a few examples of measuring similarities between words and and performing an analogy. But I am only using perhaps 10% of the total corpus as it takes a long time to train.

I am not sure what is wrong, perhaps I am not training on enough data? I imagine, based on the way it works, the model will need to see all these words in different context to add more structure to the embedding. So then I tried to train on the whole corpus, but now it seems my hidden dimension (128) is too short (whole corpus has 125k vocab words). I say because the accuracy improvements are slowing down way too much. I don't think it'll improve past 40% prediction accuracy.

My main question is how should I think about fitting the CBOW to the NY Times Corpus Dataset to get reasonable embeddings for clustering, similarities, and analogies? Any advice is appreciated (but I am not specifically asking for advice on data or debugging). Thank you.

Comment: What implementation of CBOW do you use? Your own? The typical embeddings dimension is 200 or 300. You mention 40% prediction accuracy, what is the prediction task? How would existing pre-trained embeddings that you can download from somewhere perform on the same task?

Comment: Thank you!, Yeah I somewhat modified some skeleton code I found online. The prediction task is the standard one, using surrounding words, predict the middle. I had a small bug in my architecture. I accidentally included a ReLU by habit. After removing, the embeddings look much nicer. Here is my repo with word similarities in the README https://github.com/dzheng-pitt/word_vector_representation